# How to find the indices of matching rows between 2 data frames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, performance, optimization

I have 2 dataframes with a partially matching column:

```py
data_a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
data_b = ['b', 'd', 'f', 'h']
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data_a, columns=['data'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data_b, columns=['data'])
```

I would like to get the indices match between the data in `df2` to `df1`.
Something like:

```py
indices = [1, 3, 5, None]
```

So the 0 index row of `df2` matches the 1 index row of `df1`, the 1 index row of `df2` matches the 3 index row of `df1`, etc...

If no match, then the value is `None` or any negative value.
It may be assumed there will be a single match (The data columns are unique in their values).

I could do it in a loop, yet it is slow.
I am looking for efficient way to get this or something similar.

Comment: You wish to get [isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html) with indices in place of the boolean array?

Comment: @vahvero, I am after the indices. `isin` won't do it for my needs.

Answer (score 3):

Should work as long as values in `df1` are unique and hashable --

```py
>>> s1 = df1['data']
>>> s2 = df2['data']

>>> s3 = pd.Series(data=s1.index, index=s1)
>>> s3
data
a    0
b    1
c    2
d    3
e    4
f    5
dtype: int64

>>> s2.map(s3)
0    1.0
1    3.0
2    5.0
3    NaN
Name: data, dtype: float64

>>> s2.map(s3).fillna(-1).astype(int).to_list()
[1, 3, 5, -1]
```

Answer (score 2):

[`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html), then left-[`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
df2.merge(df1.reset_index(), on='data', how='left')
```

Output:

```
  data  index
0    b    1.0
1    d    3.0
2    f    5.0
3    h    NaN
```

Note that if you have several matches, this will create additional rows:

```
data_a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'b', 'f']
data_b = ['b', 'd', 'f', 'h']
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data_a, columns=['data'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data_b, columns=['data'])
out = df2.merge(df1.reset_index(), on='data', how='left')

  data  index
0    b    1.0
1    b    4.0
2    d    3.0
3    f    5.0
4    h    NaN
```

Comment: In my case it can be assumed each row matches at most only once. I can't up vote your answer due my low credit :-(.

Answer (score 1):

```
df = df2.merge(df1.reset_index(), on='data', how='left')[["index"]]
df
```

Gives as output:

```
    index
0   1.0
1   3.0
2   5.0
3   NaN
```

Then, applying:

```
indices = df.astype('Int64').replace({pd.NA: None})['index'].tolist()
indices
```

Gives the desired list:

```
[1, 3, 5, None]
```